# How to run function while also returning value in python

Tags: python

I am currently running a program that has a robot shifting piles of "beepers".

I want to be able to return a value from a function while also running that function. When I run the function, it stops the program. I'm using a module called pyKarel which is creates a robot and beepers. count_beepers_1_1 and count_beepers_2_1 are global variables, and count_beepers_1 and count_beepers_2 are local variables that are defined within the `shiftPiles` method. I want to save over the local variables into the global variables. Here is my code

```
def shiftPiles(arg, count_beepers_1, count_beepers_2):
   #shift the piles of beepers
   return count_beepers_1, count_beepers_2


while piles > 0:
   count_beepers_1_1, count_beepers_2_2 = shiftPiles(bob, count_beepers_1_1, count_beepers_2_1)
```

Comment: I believe you can set multiple returns in your statement if nothing else is reached. so if count_beepers_1 != 0: .... return "blah" elif count_beepers_2 != .... return 'blah'  else: ... return 'endblah'

Comment: I would like to return both not one or the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've pretty well defined the problem: you want two chunks of code to execute simultaneously, and a function call doesn't do that.

This is a classic application for multiprocessing.  Python has support packages for multiple processes, multiple threads (should you determine that you can use that as well).

Also look at the possibility of using a generator -- a "function" that yields one value on each call, but each successive call starts where the last one left off.